# How to modify category.php to list posts alphabetically?

Tags: categories

As the title says. Would be grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: The (relevant part of) your theme's `category.php` file might be a helpful addition to this question.

Comment: I'm just using the default twenty twelve theme at the moment

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say was I'm using a child of the default theme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do all theme modifications in functions.php whenever possible. It keeps the theme files clean and uncluttered. Here's an example using the [`pre_get_posts` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

```
function order_category_archives( $query ) {
  if ( is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ){ // is_category() can specify a category, if necessary
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_category_archives' );
```

Notice that this uses [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) to modify the query only if we're looking at a category archive page. An optional parameter can be added to specify which category (or categories) this should be limited to.

Finally, we use [`is_main_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) to avoid modifying any additional queries that may be on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am unsure on how to use this. I am using a child theme of default twenty twelve. I copied functions.php into my child theme and pasted this function and action into it, but apparently I'm not allowed to have two functions.php? So I pasted this into the original functions.php. I then wrote pre_get_posts() into category.php but I guess that's wrong as well. Sorry I know zip about Wordpress coding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry would like to clarify after reading my comment. What happened after I use pre_get_posts() in category.php is I got the Fatal Error: Call to a member function is_main_query() on a non-object. What should I do? Thank you

Comment: I accidentally figured it ou. Thanks a lot! This was a good solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
<ul>

<?php

    // we add this, to show all posts in our
    // Glossary sorted alphabetically
    if (is_category())
    {
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' =&gt; -1, 'orderby'=&gt; 'title', 'order' =&gt; 'ASC' );

        $glossaryposts = get_posts( $args );
    }

    foreach( $glossaryposts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>;

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: This won't actually work, since the secondary loop is an *entirely new query*, that doesn't reference the main query - and therefore won't actually display posts queried *by* the main query, i.e. *the specific category's posts*.